# How to fix app emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am using android studio and whenever I try to open the app emulator to view the current app the previous app I was working on comes up instead of the current.

Is there a way to refresh it?

I also haven't been able to find any similar questions online.

Comment: Are you running the project when you open the emulator? When you run it, the new app should open on top of the old one

Comment: Yes I am running it but the app still isn't showing up.